# I installed react-native-barcode-builder and I get a blank rectangle

Tags: react-native

I installed react-native-barcode-builder and react-native-svg, but I get a blank rectangle when I want to show it. Any solution?

```
<Barcode value='Hello' format="CODE128" />
```

Comment: Can you show me the overall code?

Comment: Show me code or refer this link:https://snack.expo.io/S1E0Gbd64

Comment: I solved it. Thanks